# How do I increase or decrease the items in my shopping cart?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have some problems with the shopping cart, which I wrote down one by one.

1.When I want to increase the number of items,The item counter is common to all items in the shopping cart, meaning that if the first item is 3, the next item will start with 4.
What is the problem?

2.It also writes prices for the latest item for everyone.

3.when I confirm the final purchase, how do I empty the shopping cart?

4.And how do I calculate the total price of the products?

card adapter(FacultyAdapter)

```
 dbhandler mydb;

int a=0;
int counter=1;
int baseprice=1;
private Context context;
private String mes="";
private List<Faculty> facultyList;

public FacultyAdapter(Context context, List<Faculty> facultyList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.facultyList=facultyList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public FacultyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.itemcard,parent,false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    view.setLayoutParams(lp);

    return new FacultyViewHolder(view);
}


 /////////////////////////////////////////////////
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final FacultyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Faculty s = facultyList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(s.getName());
    holder.price.setText(s.getPrice());
    baseprice=Integer.parseInt(s.getPrice());
    String photoname=s.getImage();

    Glide
            .with(context)
            .load( Urls.image+photoname)
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .error(R.drawable.logo)
           .into(holder.img);


    mydb=new dbhandler(context);

    holder.remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                String e=s.getId().toString();
                mydb.delete(e);
               notifyDataSetChanged();                     
        }

    });
```

increment and decrement button

```
   holder.inc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           int tprice=0;
           Increment();
           holder.count.setText(""+counter);
           tprice= baseprice * counter;
           holder.price.setText(""+tprice);

       }
   });
    holder.dec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int tprice=0;
            Deccrement();
            holder.count.setText(""+counter);
            tprice= baseprice * counter;
            holder.price.setText(""+tprice);

        }
    });
}
    ////////////////////////////////////////

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return facultyList.size();
  }
    ////////////////////////////////


public class FacultyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView title;
    TextView price,count;
    CircleImageView img;
    CardView card;
  ImageButton remove,inc,dec;
    private FacultyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_list_item_title);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_list_item_des);
        remove = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_item);
       img=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_cart);
        inc=itemView.findViewById(R.id.increment);
        dec=itemView.findViewById(R.id.decrement);
        count=itemView.findViewById(R.id.count);
        card = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);
    }
  }
```

increment and decrement function

```
private void Increment(){
    counter++;
}
private void Deccrement(){
    if (counter==1)
        return;
    else {
        counter--;
    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1 and 2  `int counter=1; int baseprice=1` should not be class variable for that you can make a variable in your model class and retrieve the value from your model.

Question 3. How you are getting data into adapter by Rest API or SQLLite database. If you are getting it from rest then it should handle on your server-side and if it's in your SQLlite database then `db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_NAME);`

Question 4: If you are saving price in model class then

```
long sum = 0;
for (Faculty m : facultyList) { // or whatever your local variable is
sum += m.ttotal();
}
```

Hope this helps you...